# Encryption that allows performing mathematical operations on encrypted numbers?

Tags: encryption

Suppose I have a game with high scores posted on online leaderboards. Cheaters cheat the leaderboards by altering the score in memory before they are posted.

I think a solution would be to encrypt numbers stored in memory, and only decrypt when the scores are shown to users. Send the encrypted scores to the online leaderboards.

But I perceive a problem with this solution: Can one do math operations on encrypted values? What encryption technique allows that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big problem with your use case is that the key will have to be somewhere in the memory so that you can cipher/decipher data, so if a "bad" user has enough knowledge to change the in memory high score, it shouldn't be difficult for him to also find the key.

However, I might be wrong or your "true" question is if one can perform math operation over encrypted values. The answer for that is yes, with [homomorphic encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption).

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! I dont have encryption background so google search is useless(dont know what to search). however, are you saying that this method for the use case is not really secure since the key is stored in memory? i wonder if it practical to stored the key in the server and the only way to know the real value is to send the encrypted value to the server to be decrypted. this would require almost online all the time to play the game. thanks.

Comment: What prevents the same people who'd otherwise be patching memory locations to alter the cleartext leaderboards, from changing the encrypted leaderboards? If the software alters the [encrypted] leaderboards, then the user running the software may learn to do so too, no?

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt score, decrypt at any time you need to do math operations and encrypt it back;
 Basically you need in OOP terms setter that encrypts scores or any other information and getter that returns decrypted scores, so in memory you would always store encrypted info

Comment: the problem with decrypt before doing math operation is the value is similar to the value displayed to the user, hence the user can use that info to find the value in memory. or i misunderstood you.